# JQuery анимация ожидания ajax (post) запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, анимация

Уважаемые специалисты прошу помощи, помогите советом. Хочу сделать анимацию ожидания выполнения ajax запросов. В интернете советуют приблизительно следующий алгоритм:

```
simpleFunction() {
    startLoadingAnimation(); //отображает подложку с анимацией (описывать не буду)
    $.get("/ajaxtest.php" ............); //сам запрос
    stopLoadingAnimation(); //после выполнения скрывает анимацию
}

<input onclick="simpleFunction();">
```

Все вроде понятно, а что делать если у меня таких функции около 15-ти, в каждую добавлять эти два вызова функций отображения/скрытия анимации? А нельзя ли (чтобы не повторятся) сделать как-нибудь так?

```
animation(funct) {
     startLoadingAnimation(); //отображает подложку с анимацией
     eval(funct); //вызывает нужную функцию переданную как строку 
     stopLoadingAnimation(); //после выполнения скрывает анимацию
}

function editQuestion(param1) { ..... }

function addQuestion(param1, param2) { ..... }

//вызов функции, с передачей в качестве параметра наименование выполняемой функции 
<input onclick="animation(editQuestion('param1'));"> 

//вызов другой функции к примеру
<input onclick="animation(addQuestion('param1', 'param2'));">
```

Или как это сделать красивее? Я новичок сильно не ругайте, прошу совета

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял то тебе подойдет такой вариант.

```
function simpleFunction(param1, param2) {
  startLoadingAnimation();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log("success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
    stopLoadingAnimation();
    console.log("complete");
  });
}
```

Естественно, `console.log()` можно убрать.

Подробнее: [здесь](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Нет, я наверно не совсем понятно изъяснился, у меня около 15 функций в которых в каждой ajax запрос, добавлять в каждую startLoadingAnimation(); stopLoadingAnimation(); не правильно с точки зрения архитектуры. (и еще в каждой ставить флаг предотвращения повторной отправки), Хочу передавать функцию с параметрами как строку и затем вызывать её с помощью eval(). Желаемого я добьюсь, но хочу знать как это вообще правильно делается, может есть способ лучше?

Comment: чуть чуть подправил код в вопросе, может сейчас станет яснее

Comment: Понял, как вариант написать функцию принимающую как аргумент функцию > [скриншот](http://prntscr.com/n6z3et)

Comment: В таком случае вызов который ты привел в пример должен сработать `<input onclick="animation(editQuestion('param1'));"> `

Comment: спасибо, благодарю за помощь